# How to write Unit test for my blocks in magento 2

Tags: magento2, unit-tests

I have created a module and its working fine.

I want to write Unit test for it(i know that i should write unit test before writing code).

I tried this way , but i am not clear about it.

**My Block File** - (**app\code\Mycompany\Careers\Block\Index**)

```
<?php 
namespace Mycompany\Careers\Block\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

protected $_careersFactory;
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context, 
    \Mycompany\Careers\Model\CareersFactory $careersFactory,
    array $data = []) {
    $this->_careersFactory = $careersFactory;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);

  }


 protected function _prepareLayout()
 {
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
 }

/**
* this function return all the jobs currently active in careers extension
**/
  public function getAllCareers(){

    $Careers = $this->_careersFactory->create();
    $collection = $Careers->getCollection();
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('active',1);

    return $collection->setOrder('sort_order','ASC');
  }//End of function getHomepageBanners
}
```

I created my unit test file like this
file **IndexTest.php** - (**app\code\Mycompany\Careers\Test\Unit\Block**)

```
<?php
namespace Mycompany\Careers\Test\Unit\Block;
use Mycompany\Careers\Block\Index\Index;

class IndexTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
   protected $careers;

   public function setUp()
   {
    $objectManager = new \Magento\Framework\TestFramework\Unit\Helper\ObjectManager($this);
    $this->careers = $objectManager->getObject('Mycompany\Careers\Block\Index\Index');

   }

   public function testGetAllCareers(){

      //What should i want to write here?

   }
}
```

for this what should i write in side my **testGetAllCareers()** method?.
What else i want to do for this?